# How do I get an SSL certificate for a server?

Tags: ssl, ssl-certificate, logstash

So I am trying to access a server using a software (Logstash) in which I am trying to push data to the server (which runs an HDFS environment).

In order to access the server, the software configuration file asks me for the **"ssl_cert"** and **"ssl_key"**.   What does this mean?

I have a private key "exaLeap_key.pem" so I am assuming that is what I put for "ssl_key".  Then what do I put for **"ssl_cert"**?   Do I need to generate the SSL cert and install on the server?  Does the certificate validate the server to client or the client to the server?  How can I configure this?

```
output  {
        webhdfs {
                host => "<IP Address>"
                port => 50070
                path => "/home/hadoop/datafromlogstash/data.csv"
                user => "hadoop"
                use_ssl_auth => true
                ssl_cert => "usr/username/exaLeap_key.pem" //<---- ? What do I put here?
                ssl_key => "usr/username/exaLeap_key.pem"
        }
}
```

Fyi, I can SSH to the server by using just the private key, so I don't undersatnd why I am being asked for a certificate.
The SSH command I'm using:

```
 ssh -i ~/exaLeap_key.pem hadoop@ec2-54-169-72-60.ap-southeast-1.compute.amazonaws.com
```

Comment: See https://discuss.elastic.co/t/encrypting-the-certificate-key-for-ssl/100205/2  looks like the key file is the encrypted passphrase for your ssl_cert.

Comment: The ssl_cert is not mandatory in the configuration of this output plugin. You could try without and see if it works.

Comment: I think the ssl_cert parameter is the cert associated with the private key you're using, which just be in the same file as the private key.